# regarding transform a one way list into a two-dimensional array representing a mesh grid

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have a data set saved as following. Generally speaking, it is a list, each element of this master list is a sublist. Each sublist includes two elements, where the first one is a value, and the second one is ID.

```
[[0.089, 0],
 [0.075, 1],
 [0.588, 2],
 [0.906, 3],
 [0.332, 4],
 [0.707, 5],
 [0.668, 6],
 [0.426, 7],
 [0.034, 8]]
```

The above test data set can be generated using the following code segment

```
import numpy as np
testlist=[]
for i in range(9):
    temp=[]
    x1 = np.random.rand()
    temp.append(x1)
    temp.append(i)
    testlist.append(temp)
```

How to transfer this list into the two-dimensional array representing a mesh. For instance, the values will be arranged in this two-dimensional array

```
0.089  0.045  0.588
0.907  0.332  0.707
0.668  0.426 0.034
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

the reshape will change array's shape, -1 in shape means the value will be infered by numpy itself

```py
arr = np.array([[0.089, 0],
 [0.075, 1],
 [0.588, 2],
 [0.906, 3],
 [0.332, 4],
 [0.707, 5],
 [0.668, 6],
 [0.426, 7],
 [0.034, 8]])

arr[:,0].reshape(-1,3).copy()
```

**Result**

```
array([[0.089, 0.075, 0.588],
       [0.906, 0.332, 0.707],
       [0.668, 0.426, 0.034]])
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. by the way, after the reshape operation, why do we still need copy()?

Comment: you need copy if you want to assign the result to different array and keep the arr intact. because reshape doesn't make copy changing another array will result in changing the main array

Comment: You can also do `new_arr = arr.reshape(-1,3,2)` if you still need the ID's, which is `new_arr[:,:,1]`.